# Can't figure out correct query whith logical condition in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm totally newby in Mongoose and I'm sorry for a probably stupid question, but I really need someones help.

Model has two fields: `major_rating` and `minor_rating`. I have one member:

```
example = {'major_rating': N1, 'minor_rating': N2}
```

and I need to find the amount of members satisfying this condition:

```
major_rating > N1 || (major_rating == N1 && minor_rating >= N2)
```

Please help me figure it out, there must be better way than to make two queries:

```
.where('major_rating').gt(N1).count(..)

.where('major_rating').equals(N1).where('minor_rating').gte(N2).count(..)
```

and add the results to each other.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [or operator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html) in Mongoose that will allow you to do what you want. You'll need to fall back to the MongoDB conditionals to do more advanced queries in Mongoose. For information on all of those you can use the [regular MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or).

The example below should solve your problem or at least get you started:

```
.or([{major_rating: {$gt: N1}}, {major_rating: N1, minor_rating: {$gte: N2}}]).count()
```